# DeleteView in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have this view that allows me to delete data. But the I keep getting the this error below whenever I click on the delete button. what I want to archive is when a user clicks the on GUARDAR, that model data should be deleted. But I keep getting the NoReverseMatch error bellow

```
 raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'book_delete' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$']
```

```
View.py

def book_delete(request, pk):
    envío = get_object_or_404(Control, pk=pk)
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        envío.delete()
        data['form_is_valid'] = True
        envíos = Control.objects.all().order_by('-fecha')
        data['html_book_list'] = render_to_string('includes/partial_envio_list.html', {
            'envíos': envíos
        })
    else:
        context = {'envío': envío}
        data['html_form'] = render_to_string('includes/partial_envío_delete.html', context, request=request)
    return JsonReson
```

```
Model.py

class Control(models.Model):
    control_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    familia = models.ForeignKey(Familia, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    estado = models.ForeignKey(Estado, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    Fecha_desde = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    Fecha_hasta = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    control_id_hash = models.CharField(max_length=260, db_collation='utf8_unicode_ci')
    control_codigo = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_collation='utf8_unicode_ci')
```

```
URL
path('envío/<int:pk>/delete/', views.book_delete, name='book_delete'),
```

```
template


<form method="post" action="{% url 'agric:book_delete' control.pk %}" class="js-book-delete-form">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        <div class="modal-status bg-danger"></div>
        <div class="modal-body text-center py-4">

            <h3>Are you sure?</h3>
            <p class="lead">Do you really want to delete envío <strong>{{ control.control_codigo }}</strong>?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer" style="background:#f4f5f7">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bs-dismiss="modal">CANCELAR</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn modelbuttun btn-danger ">GUARDAR</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</fo
```

Comment: check what is under {{ control }}, it seems {{ control.pk }} is not an integer, but a tuple

Comment: Still not getting it @alex